# JustMock - How to mock a method for all instances by returning the result of the equivalent method of another class (sharing a common interface

Tags: justmock, arrange-act-assert

I am working with .NET 4.5, EF6 and I'm trying to use JustMock 2.0 to test my application.

I am trying to mock my database by mocking my *DbContext* subclass: *CoreDataRepositoryContext*.

To do it, I need to mock the member *SaveChanges* of *DbContext* and every *DbSet* typed properties of my class *CoreDataRepositoryContext* by returning a fake data collection. I also need to mock the following *DbSet*'s members:

- Add
- Remove
- AsQueryable

I need to mock it for all instances of *CoreDataRepositoryContext* and *DbSet*

For example, I have entities of type *Order* in database (table *Orders*)
I did the following to mock the table *Orders*:

```
// FakeOrders is a list of orders (List<Order>)

var mockedContext = Mock.Create<CoreDataRepositoryContext>();

   // Mock works
Mock.Arrange(() => mockedContext.SaveChanges()).IgnoreInstance().DoNothing();
   // Mock works
Mock.Arrange(() => mockedContext.Orders).IgnoreInstance().ReturnsCollection(FakeOrders);
   // Mock works
Mock.Arrange(() => mockedContext.Orders.Add(Arg.IsAny<Order>())).IgnoreInstance().DoInstead((Order o) => FakeOrders.Add(o));
   // Mock works
Mock.Arrange(() => mockedContext.Orders.Remove(Arg.IsAny<Order>())).IgnoreInstance().DoInstead((Order o) => FakeOrders.Remove(o));
   // Mock DOES NOT work !
Mock.Arrange(() => mockedContext.Orders.AsQueryable()).IgnoreInstance().Returns(() => FakeOrders.AsQueryable());
```

*mockedContext.Orders* is of type *DbSet< Order >* and FakeOrders is of type *List< Order >*. Both classes implement the interface *IEnumerable< Order >*.

Mocking *Add* and *Remove* members work well because neither of the two methods is declared in the interface *IEnumerable< T >*.

On the other hand, *AsQueryable* is declared in this interface and defined by *Queryable*. So, as I mock the member using *IgnoreInstance*, calling *AsQueryable* from an instance of any class which implements *IEnumerable< T >* launches a never ending loop. Because *IEnumerable< Order >.AsQueryable* is mocked by *FakeOrders.AsQueryable* which is mocked by... *FakeOrders.AsQueryable*... infinite loop...

```
var query = mockedContext.Orders.AsQueryable(); // Infinite loop
query = FakeOrders.AsQueryable(); // Infinite loop
query = new List<Order>().AsQueryable(); // Infinite loop
```

**How can I do to only mock *DbSet< Order >.AsQueryable* specifically, without mocking *IEnumerable< Order >.AsQueryable* using *IgnoreInstance*?**

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have finally found a workaround:

I don't arrange DbContext with `IgnoreInstance` but I arrange the constructor of my `DbContext` subclass when called with a specific connection string as argument:

```
string myConnectionString = "CoreDBTestConnection";

// Arrange all CoreDataRepositoryContext instances for this connection string
Mock.Arrange(() => new CoreDataRepositoryContext(myConnectionString).Returns(GetMockContext());
```

The constructor is replaced by `GetMockContext()` which retruns a mocked context:

```
private static CoreDataRepositoryContext GetMockContext()
{
        CoreDataRepositoryContext mockContext = new CoreDataRepositoryContext();

        Mock.Arrange(() => mockContext.SaveChanges()).DoNothing();

        Mock.Arrange(() => mockContext.Set<Order>()).ReturnsCollection(FakeOrders);
        Mock.Arrange(() => mockContext.Orders).ReturnsCollection(FakeOrders);
        Mock.Arrange(() => mockContext.Orders.Add(Arg.IsAny<Order>())).DoInstead((Order o) => FakeOrders.Add(o));
        Mock.Arrange(() => mockContext.Orders.Remove(Arg.IsAny<Order>())).DoInstead((Order o) => FakeOrders.Remove(o));
        Mock.Arrange(() => mockContext.Orders.Find(Arg.IsAny<object[]>())).Returns((object[] param) => FakeOrders.Find(x => x.Id == (Guid)param[0]));
        Mock.Arrange(() => mockContext.Orders.AsQueryable()).Returns(() => FakeOrders.AsQueryable());

        // Then arrange all DbSets...

        return mockContext;
}

public static FakeDataList<Order> FakeOrders = new List<Order>();
```

Comment: You might want to try [JustMock.EntityFramework](http://www.nuget.org/packages/JustMock.EntityFramework/) to spare yourself a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove `IgnoreInstance()` from the last arrangement. This will make it work only when called on that `Orders` property.

Although, technically, you don't need to arrange any of those methods on the `Orders` property. `ReturnsCollection` will take care to proxy all `IList<T>` and all `IQueryable<T>` methods to the target (if the target implements any of those interfaces). Since `FakeOrders` is a List, then `Add` and `Remove` on `Orders` will be proxied to the same methods on the backing collection. `AsQueryable` is not an instance method, but an extension method. As such, you can't mock it for a specific derived type, but you shouldn't even need to. The original implementation of `AsQueryable` is flexible enough, so you shouldn't need to mock it at all, ever.

If you simply remove the last three arrangements, your test will still work as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your help Stefan.

Actually, depending on the logic of the business layer of my application, I have to use `IgnoreInstance`. In fact I am trying to test _Managers_ which create a new _Repository_ and then a new `CoreDataRepositoryContext` each time they need to access the database. So, I arrange `CoreDataRepositoryContext` regardless the instance in the _ClassInitialize_ method of my test class to cover all tests.

I tried to only arrange the `Orders` property without arranging any methods but it doesn't work and my database is solicited when those methods are called.